# Windows 7 VPN Error 766

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, certificate

I tried to reinstall my windows. Now I have two user accounts. One of them can connect to a VPN while the other cannot. It is really strange... It gives the error 766 listed below.

> Connecting to vpn.cuhk.edu.hk using 'WAN Miniport (L2TP)'...
>
> Error 766 : A certificate could not be found. Conenctions that use the L2TP >protocol over IPSec require the installation of a machine certificate, also known >as a computer certificate.

Anyone knows why they are different in two accounts? Any suggestion to work on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes met this problems,too.
It is advisable for you to refresh it and connect it again. if it still does not work, or try this

If you use PPTP VPN, select Automatic in Type of VPN.
If you use L2TP, check the remote access server and make sure there is certificate in the computer certificate store.

Related Topics
VPN error codeVPN Error 720 - the connection attempt failed because your computer and the remote computer could not agree on PPP control protocol - Case 2 ...
http://www.chicagotech.net/vpnerrors.htm

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to check the remote access server and computer certificate store. Mind if you explain how to access them?